# Removing input fields in Reactjs with values not reseting (Still preserves previous values)

Tags: reactjs

Following fiddle link have example code.

https://jsfiddle.net/KishoreBarik/f8h3c82m/

Removing an element is not working. While deleting first element removes the last element. Operations json got updated correctly but UI not rendering IT properly.

Someone felp me to fix this issue.

Comment: Try to use lodash instead slice, it helped me.

Comment: @Andrew ...If possible please update jsfiddle. i am not getting what is the issue here....

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/f8h3c82m/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/f8h3c82m/2/) Here correct removing items. I used delete insted splice or lodash.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew